# Better errors in console after compiling scripts using Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've stumbled across it a couple of times now, where I get an error in the console, and I'm unable to figure out where it origins, without wild guesses. Such as this error here:

[image: JavaScript console error - Webpack]

I can see that there are [this NPM-package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin) that shows better Webpack-errors, when compiling. But I'm looking for something that makes it easier to track errors in the console, to the part of the code that triggers it.

Like this above-displayed error. Why is it, that it doesn't pass the string, that it's trying to pass as an SVG? I've clicked all the links displayed on the error, but the one that comes closest to helping is the last line, which is the function being executed when the viewport is resized.

Are there a way, where I easier can shine light on, what causes the given error?

---

**Addition1:**

Or an error like this:

[image: cannot tween a null target]

Why not write the line, where the 'null target' is fetched, so the developer has something to work with. It's like saying: 'Somewhere in your code there is a null target'. Go figure it out. :-/

I know that it is a tall order, - but am I the only one with this problem?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear here, somewhere in your component (that you've blurred out) you're trying to treen a target element that doesn't exist

Comment: I know that's it's in my component. But that component is 1000 lines long. So I'm trying to make it easier to find were 'somewhere'.

Comment: If your component is 1000 lines long, you have an issue. You should be separating out logic into smaller components

Comment: Maybe you're right. Regardless... You're not answering my question. I'm looking for a better way to figure out, where errors in the console appear in the code. Even if I had merely 10 lines of code, - it's an advantage to know exactly, which line is the null target or an invalid svg.

Comment: The better way IS breaking down your god components into smaller components. What's harder, dealing with 1000 lines or 50 lines?

Comment: Derek is right about the components, BUT he's not answering the question. Right under ```entry``` in webpack, config, add ```devtool: 'source-map',``` see if that helps with the errors

Comment: @Zeth, what about Pause on exception functionality (in Chrome, etc.)? If you combine it with sourcecode file as guys suggest, you can narrow this issue down in your long file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Zeth, I think you're looking for source maps! It will point from the line in your compiled output, to the line in your source files.

Check these out for more information:

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map